# Email account password storage in Java/Mysql server program

Tags: java, mysql, email, passwords

I am in a sticky situation where I am writing an application that sends out emails to clients using an email account of my company. The issue here is that I have to have the password for the account to make the mail service on the server send out emails from that account. I know that passwords should never be stored in plain text, particularly ones that are used for an important email account. The dilemma here is that the program NEEDS to have the actual plain text password to send the emails so it needs to be stored somewhere accessible by the program. The program uses a MySQL database to store information so there are three options in my mind:

1) Store the password in the program's memory, i.e. a private final String field.

2) A file on the on the server where the password can be read from

3) Somewhere in the MySQL database.

I would think that 1 is the safest option, but does anybody have ideas to handle this sort of situation to minimize risk of the password falling into the wrong hands? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can send e-mail with a custom `From:` header without that account's credentials. Ever get spam e-mail from your own e-mail address?

Comment: No, never actually. I don't quite understand what you mean. I am using Apache Commons Email if that would help you explain better.

Comment: I mean that you can do `email.setFrom("someone@example.com");` but still send it via your own SMTP server. With the right DNS records (look into SPF and DKIM) it'll pass spam filters without trouble.

Comment: Ah, so the setAuthentication method is not necessary to send emails from an account?

Comment: How will your application be launched? Will it be kicked off automatically by a cron/invoked in some way? Or will it be manually started by a user? That helps determine what your best options are.

Comment: The application is run in tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments pointing out that SMTP doesn't require authentication are correct.  That said, *all three* of the options you specified are insecure, assuming that the server uses commodity hardware and software.  I'll show why each is insecure, although I won't follow your original order.

> 2) A file on the on the server where the password can be read from
>
> 3) Somewhere in the MySQL database.

What if someone were to steal the server?  Then, they could just open the file or the database, read the password, and immediately have access to all the important information in the company.  So unless you have armed guards surrounding the server day and night, this is already pretty insecure.

But it gets worse.  No computer system is completely invulnerable to attack, and several well-publicized attacks (Sony's PlayStation Network, for example) in the past few years have shown that an attacker can get to the contents of disk files and databases without physical access.  Furthermore, it seems from your question that the server in question is meant to accept packets (HTTP requests, incoming emails, etc.) from the outside world, which boosts your attack surface.

> 1) Store the password in the program's memory, i.e. a private final String field.

This is tempting, but this is even more pernicious than option 2 or option 3.  For one thing, a private final string field is stored in the .class file generated by the Java compiler, so with this option you are already storing the unencrypted password on the server's hard drive.  After compromising the server as in option 2 or 3, an attacker can just run `javap` in order to get the plaintext password out of the .class file.

This approach broadens your attack surface even more, though.  If the password is stored as part of the source code, suddenly it's available to all developers who are working on the code.  Under the principle of least privilege, the developers shouldn't know extra passwords, and there's a very good reason here.  If any of the *developers'* machines is stolen or compromised from outside, the attacker can look through the compromised machine's hard drive and get the plaintext password.  Then there's source control.  One of the really important benefits of source control is that it allows you to inspect any prior version of your code.  So even if you switch to a secure method in the future, if the password has ever entered source control then the source control server is a potential attack point.

All of these factors add up to show that, even if the HTTP/mail server's security is top-notch, option 1 increases the attack surface so much that the HTTP/mail server's security doesn't really help.

---

Extra detail:  At the beginning I specified "assuming that the server uses commodity hardware and software."  If you aren't using commodity hardware and software, you can do things like boot from readonly storage and use only an encrypted database, requiring a person to provide the decryption key on every boot.  After that, the decrypted information lives in memory only, and is never written to disk.  This way, if the server is stolen, an attacker has to unplug the server and so loses all the decrypted information that was only ever in memory.  This kinds of setup is sometimes used for a Kerberos KDC (with the server in a locked boxe for extra security), but is rarely used otherwise, and is frankly overkill when there is an easy way to solve your problem without going to all this extra expense.

Answer (score 1):

If you were serious about keeping it safe, you could encode the password and put it in 2 or 3.  When you need to use it, simply have your program decode it and save it in memory as a plain string.

ex.

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
```

`String decodedUrl = URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8")`;

Comment: Right, so this would be a "symmetric" encryption technique. Could you elaborate on why 2 or 3 are safer than 1? If somebody gets on the file system is decompiling a class file easier than finding the password in a text file?

Comment: Well #1 would ultimately be safer.  But if you ever need to change it, 2 and 3 would be alot easier

Comment: That approach would be more like security through obscurity. If someone had access to your database, they could run the decoding themselves. Sure, it would take them slightly more time to determine the encoding format than if it were plain text, but it wouldn't stop them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. You can store the password in MYSQL in a blob field applying AES encryption on the insert; using and keeping the key_string in java for handy decryption.

MYSQL Syntax :

`AES_ENCRYPT(str,key_str)`

and

`AES_DECRYPT(crypt_str,key_str)`

The insert would be similar to the following:

`INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,AES_ENCRYPT('password','encryption_key'));`

You would use the key to decrypt coming out

`SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password, 'encryption_key') AS unencrypted FROM t`

So you never store the password as plain text in your application although you will need the encryption key. Your connection to the database should be secure. Logs may be an issue.

Alternately you could use stored procs to get the keys in and out or you could encrypt them server side and insert/retrieve after encrypted.

Comment: In my example I would assume that the database and server are on remote locations and not co-located. The application can also retrieve the encryption keys in a secure manner at runtime. You wouldn't store any of this in clear text anywhere. Enterprise databases like Oracle also have strategies that can be leveraged. 

There is a cost to rolling your own but assuming this isn't fort knox you may not need an enterprise solution. Plenty of solutions exist, one way hashs with salts to prevent equal passwords from having the same encyted strings, etc. It depends on your needs.